# When to update my persistent storage (core data)?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, persistent-storage

I have a NSObject that I manipulate quite a lot, as the user changes different things. It seems a bit crazy to update the core data every single time there is a change. It would require a lot of coding just for one little change in these different places.

When should I update the core data if I want my stuff to persist? Is it a bad idea to only update it before the app closes?

Thanks

Comment: You could also say it's crazy to build your storage solution so that you have to save a huge amount of information every time anything changes - if you're not actually storing much, then just save it every time, if you have a lot to store, then split it up into blocks, and save what you need.  As @Sneak says - it is up to you to decide how much data you can reasonably afford to lose

Comment: is it an NSManagedObject? in that case you can just call .save() on you NSManagedObjectContext and the changes will get saved. Only one line of code.

Answer (score 3):

> When should I update the core data if I want my stuff to persist?

Basically, you save whenever you feel that the changes are significant enough and **should be saved.**

> Is it a bad idea to only update it before the app closes?

If the changes are important and you don't want them to get lost, what do you think happens in case the app crashes or terminates, battery dies etc..? Well, all the changes get lost if you havn't saved it.

> It seems a bit crazy to update the core data every single time there
>   is a change.

Well, the application can not magically know what is important to you that should be saved and what would not. This is how it works generally for everything.

So basically, thats the guideline, the rest is up to you.